# XSLTタスクであるフォルダの配下のxsdファイルをすべて処理する．

Tags: xslt

初心者の質問ですみません．
antのxsltタスクで、あるフォルダの下のすべてのxsdファイル（*.xsd）を処理したいのです．

xsltタスクにはincludesfileプロパティがあり、"the name of a file. Each line of this file is taken to be an include pattern"と説明されています．この属性をどのように自動的にantで作成できるでしょうか？

以上 よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

失礼しました．includesfileではなく、basedirを設定してから

```
includes="*.xsd"
```

で一発で実現できました．